# zsh (vs. bash) parameter expansion anomaly

Tags: zsh

If you execute the script

```
X=abcd
echo ${1:-$X}
echo ${1?$X}
```

without passing any parameter, and do it under bash, it outputs

```
abcd
./mrh.sh: line 3: 1: abcd
```

If you run it under zsh, it outputs

```
abcd
mrh.sh:3: 1: -$X
```

We see that in the case of ${...?...}, the substitution ($X) is expanded under bash, but not under zsh. In the case of ${...:-...}, $X is expanded in both bash and zsh.

I looked up the zsh man page to find an explanation, why no substitution of $X takes place in the second case, but could not find anything. Is it a bug in zsh?

Using zsh 5.0.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation actually can be found in the man pages of *zsh* ([*zshexpn(1)*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion)) and *bash* ([*bash(1)*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)).

For both shells substituted text is also subject to parameter expansion:

- *zshexpn(1)*:

  > […] the replacement text of any substitutions, are themselves subject to parameter expansion […]
- *bash(1)*:

  > In each of the cases below, `word` is subject to tilde expansion, parameter expansion […]

Here are the relevant parts of the substitutions in question (emphases by me):

1. For `${1:-$X}` both shells behave the same:

   - *zshexpn(1)*:

     > `${name:-word}`
     >
     > If `name` is […] is non-null, then substitute its value; otherwise **substitute `word`**.
   - *bash(1)*:

     > `${parameter:-word}`
     >
     > […] If `parameter` is unset or null, the **expansion of `word` is substituted**. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted

   While the *zsh* manpage does not explicitly mention that `word` is again expanded, this is covered by the above mentioned rule. Leading to `abcd` being printed in your example.
2. For `${1:?$X}` there is a slight difference in the wording of what *zsh* does:

   - *zshexpn(1)*:

     > `${name:?word}`
     >
     > [...] if `name` is both set and non-null, then substitute its value; otherwise, **print `word`** and exit from the shell.
   - *bash(1)*:

     > `${parameter:?word}`
     >
     > If `parameter` is null or unset, the **expansion of `word` [...] is written** to the standard error and the shell, if it is not interactive, exits.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

   For *bash* it is explicitly stated that `word` is expanded. But for *zsh* it states that `word` is printed and not substituted. That also means that it is not subject to the rule mentioned above.